# An error occured during age of empires online beta launcher

Tags: technical-issues, age-of-empires-online

I found I had a problem "An error occured" whilst patching the AOE beta for the first time.

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 2):

The solution was to go to the C:\Program Files\Microsoft Games\Project S

copy the files in the temp patch folder into the project s folder

right click  launcherupdate  > run as adminstrator

then the patcher starts working again...

Comment: The above [contributed sic](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/revisions/23283/1) by the asker

Comment: A similar error occurs when the new AOE Online game installer was not started as administrator!

Comment: @powtac you'll have to forward your comment to Adam, who originally posted the answer in the question body. All I did is extract it.